# How to display a Route by default with React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-component, react-routing

I'm new to React and I would like to develop a Single Page Application, so I'm using react-router four routing.

Below the main.js, where I specify the routes

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router,Route} from 'react-router';
import {App} from './components/App';
import {Login} from './components/Login';
import {Home} from './components/Home';
import { history } from 'react-router';

React.render(
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>

    </Route>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('main')
);
```

And then the App.js, as you can see I want to have a fixed Header and Footer, and then to have the content of the page change dinamically depending on the route.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Header} from './Header';
import {Footer} from './Footer';

export class App extends React.Component {


render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (<div>
        <Header/>
        <div className="page-content">
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <Footer/>
    </div>);
}


}
```

With this code, once the application is loaded with the path ("/"), I need to click on the link Home to display the home content, but I would like to be displayed by default, once the application is first loaded.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you probably want to use an `IndexRoute` as described [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md) in the React Router documentation.

Your router would then look something like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: did't know about IndexRoute, but it made the job! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's usefull when nested IndexRoute.

```
<div>
    <Redirect from="/" to="home"/>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="home" component={Home}>
            <IndexRoute component={IndexView} />
            <Route path="other" component={OtherView}></Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="about" component={About}></Route>

    </Route>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of `react-router`, you can use `ÌndexRedirect`. This way you're not obligated to put your home screen under the route "/". Users navigating to "/" will simply be redirected to "/home".

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRedirect to="home"/>
        <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a lot in React v6. I think you can now achieve what you want with the following  specification:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} >
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

If the specification of the App component declares it as an Outlet, the Routes code above will always render it, irrespective of whether the path is "/", "/home" or "/login". Within the nested group, "/home" or "/login" paths will then add Home or Login displays as you would expect, but a "/" path will also add Home as a "default".

Alternatively, but perhaps less comprehensibly, you can use the "index" keyword to render a default Home component within the nested group:

```
       <Route index element={<Home />} />
```